# Setup Auto-Login/Visit Specific URL?

Tags: php, html, unix, cron, automation

There is a website where I want to be logged in always to be seen 7/24 online, because there is a queue among users and you go forward more on this queue if you are more often online. I have a linux server which I am planning to use for this cause but so far I couldn't find anything useful from google. Would be glad if you can help me!

**Summary:** My server will login for me always to the website and I will be seen online even at night 3 am.

Comment: What do you exactly mean

Comment: My server will login for me always to the website and I will be seen online even at night 3 am.

Comment: Well see the answer by @Richard Reiber it's nice try it out. If it helps accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login and obtain a session with cURL (example code from the Internet):

```
$username = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypass';
$loginUrl = 'http://www.example.com/login/';

//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Set the post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user='.$username.'&pass='.$password);

//Handle cookies for the login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

//Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
//not to print out the results of its query.
//Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
//from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute the request (the login)
$store = curl_exec($ch);

//the login is now done and you can continue to get the
//protected content.

//set the URL to the protected file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/protected/download.zip');

//execute the request
$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Then you can use this cookie file later on and can just make GET-requests with cURL - for example every half hour. You should have to make a GET-request before logging in probably if tokens are used by the site you are trying to logging in on. (I had same problem with a online-learning system of a university where the professor can see how long you watched the content :-D)